# Utilizar json com PHP e MySql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

Boas eu estou a tentar usar para *Json* para preencher um formulário com alguns dados, o problema é que tenho tentado varias formas e continua sem funcionar e é  que ja tenho aqui é uma grande confusão.

1. Em Primeiro Necessário Jquery, o que esta ja adicionei.
2. Em segundo é necessário uma função javascript para fazer a ligação
   entre o cliente e o servidor.
3. Em Terceiro lugar é necessário uma pagina que vai fazer a pesquisa
   na base de dados mediante os parâmetros que são enviados.

*HTML:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xh1tml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Oficina Marcelo - Gestão de clientes</title>


    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

    <!-- Autocomplete -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='psqMat.js'></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#ref").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
                selectFirst: true
            });      
        });
    </script>
<!-- Fim Autocomplete -->    

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getRef(o) {
        var ref = o.value;
       //alert("a referencia a pesquisar é: " + ref); //Ate aqui chega e passa o valor da text
        $.ajax({
            url: "psqMat.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            type:"POST",
            data: "?ref=" + ref,
            success: function(response) {
                $("#designacao").val(response.designacao);
                if (response.marca !== undefined ) {
                    $("#marca").val(response.marca);
                }
                if (response.uniMed !== undefined ) {
                    $("#unimed").val(response.uniMed);
                }
                $("#precoUnit").val(response.precoUnit);
                if (response.iva !== undefined ) {
                    $("#iva").val(response.iva);
                }
            },
//            error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
//                    alert("shit happened: " + textStatus);
            }                            
        });
    }
</script>

<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="func.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body>

[/code]
```

*psqMat.php*:

```
<?php
include 'includes/conexao.php';
include 'includes/validaLogin.php';
  $ref = $_GET['ref'];
    $sql = "SELECT ref, designacao, ID_marca, ID_unimed, precoUnit, ID_iva FROM tb_material WHERE ref=".$ref;
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);
    // fazer queries à BD com a referencia se existir 1 e só 1 resultado vamos criar a variavel $res / com a dados necessarios (a partir do resultado do query)
    if ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $res = [
            "ref" => $r['ref'],
            "designacao" => $r['designacao'],
            "marca" => $r['ID_marca'],
            "unimed" => $r['ID_unimed'],
            "precoUnit" => $r['precoUnit'],
            "iva" => $r['ID_iva']
        ];
    }// devolver o resultado
    echo json_encode($res);
?>
[/code]

e ainda existe o ficheiro psqMat.js (o que nao sei qual é a função dele, pois ja nao sei se ainda é necessário ou nao...)
[code=javascript]

    $(document).ready( function() {
   /* Executa a requisição quando o campo CEP perder o foco */
   $('#ref').blur(function(){
      alert("Chegou " + $("#ref").value);
           /* Configura a requisição AJAX */
           $.ajax({
                url : 'psqMat.php', /* URL que será chamada */
                type : 'POST', /* Tipo da requisição */
                data: 'ref=' + $('#ref').val(), /* dado que será enviado via POST */
                dataType: 'json', /* Tipo de transmissão */
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.sucesso == 1){
                        $('#designacao').val(data.designacao);
                        $('#marca').val(data.marca);
                        $('#unimed').val(data.uniMed);
                        $('#precoUnit').val(data.precoUnit);
                        $('#iva').val(data.iva);
                        $('#qtd').focus();
                    }
                }
           });  
   return false;    
   })
});
```

Esta tudo correto ou ainda nao?

Comment: Olá Miguel, Primeiramente seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow, é interessante dá uma lida no tour pra saber como funciona as regras aqui dentro. Veja aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Faltou passar a conexão aqui => `mysqli_query($sql);`

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?